# Drafts is not updating by newly inserted values in gmail, google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I want to update or replace or insert the existing drafts using google app scripts in my gmail. I have a code below but its not inserting any text in the existing drafts.

What, I want to do is to update or insert or replace my existing drafts using google app scripts.

```
function buildAddOn(e)
{
  return generatedDrafts();
}

function generatedDrafts()
{
  tex = 'This needs to be inserted';

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var cardSection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Texts');

  cardSection.addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText(tex).setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('applyText')
  .setParameters({'updatedText':tex})));

  return card.addSection(cardSection).build();
}


function applyText(e)
{
  content = e.parameters.updatedText;

  var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder().setUpdateDraftBodyAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftBodyAction()
  .addUpdateContent(content, CardService.ContentType.TEXT).setUpdateType(CardService.UpdateDraftBodyType.IN_PLACE_INSERT)).build();

 return response; 
}
```

the appscript manifesto looks like this

```
"gmail": {
    "contextualTriggers": [
        {
            "unconditional": {},
            "onTriggerFunction": "buildAddOn"
        }
    ],
```

Can any one suggest me what I am doing wrong and how can i fix my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you created a general Add-On, not one that triggers on messages.

You want to follow [these recommendations](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui#building_a_compose_add-on) and change your manifest file to include the necessary parts.

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    //...
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    //...
  ],
  "gmail": {
    /...
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      /...
    }],
    "composeTrigger": {
      "selectActions": [
        {
          "text": "Insert Text on Emails",
          "runFunction": "insertTextAction"
        }
      ],
      "draftAccess": "METADATA"
    },
}
```

And your code should have a `insertTextAction` function that creates a Card with actions that return `UpdateDraftActionResponse`:

```
function insertTextAction(e) {
  return generatedDrafts();
}
```

After those changes, you should be good to go!

Comment: this would allow for compose actions within the draft UI, but how to have gmail addons update drafts from a contextual trigger's user interaction set with setComposeAction?